# Does $\mu(X \setminus E) = 0$ imply $E$ is dense in $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff measure space. If $E$ is such that $\mu(X \setminus E) = 0$, must $E$ be dense in $X$?

Comment: Notice this typesetting difference: $X\backslash E$ versus $X\setminus E$.  The very name, \setminus, suggests that it is intended as a binary operation symbol and would therefore be surrounded by spaces that you don't see with \backslash.  (I edited the question accordingly.)

Comment: Is the measure related to the topology in some way? Otherwise, you could just give $X$ a measure by giving every subset of $X$ measure zero. On the other hand, I think the answer to your question is yes if and only if every nonempty open set has nonzero measure (as long as your measure is positive.)

Comment: "Not dense" is the same as "disjoint from some open set".  Maybe that's most of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously not because an arbitrary measure need not have anything to do with the topology. But if you want to talk about Borel measures (=defined on the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra) such that non-empty open subsets have positive measure, then the answer is yes. Obviously $E\subseteq \overline{E}$ and therefore $\mu(X\setminus\overline{E})=0$ as well. Because $X\setminus\overline{E}$ is open, this implies $X=\overline{E}$.

Comment: Doesn't this answer require the measure to be complete, or is that implied by it being Borel?

Comment: Borel measures are not, in general, complete.

Comment: @Goos: Neither.

Comment: @JohannesHahn How are you concluding that $\mu(X \setminus \overline{E}) = 0$ then?

Comment: That has nothing to do with completeness. $\overline{E}$ is just bigger than $E$ and since $\mu(X\setminus E)=0$ was assumed, $\mu(X\setminus\overline{E})=0$ follows. This is monotonicity of measure.

Comment: @JohannesHahn That is not true though.  Monotonicity only applies to *measurable* sets, and you don't know $X \setminus \overline{E}$ is measurable.  Complete measures are precisely those measures for which a subset of a measure-zero set is measurable, so yes, I really do think you need completeness.

Comment: That's why I'm talking about Borel measures. Exactly because I need open and closed sets to be measurable.

Comment: @JohannesHahn Yes, I see now, I was just not following your logic.  I gave you plus one, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, if $\mu$ is a (non-zero) Haar measure (i.e. translation invariant Borel measure), so every non-empty open set has non-zero measure. In particular, if $E$ was not dense, then there would exist $x\in X$ and a non-empty open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ that does not intersect $E$. Since $\mu$ is Haar you have $\mu(U)\neq 0$. But also
$$\mu(U)\leq \mu(X\setminus E)=0$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Very nice! ${}{}{}$

Comment: May I ask why the -2?